# add-in sso error 13003 on desktop, but I'm a O365 work account, why?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I'm using a work account and I believe that both the manifest and the application registration are configured correctly for add-in sso. I'm using the most up to date build that has been pushed to our org, build Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13029.20342) 64-bit.

```
{
"status":"failed","error":{"name":"User identity type is not supported.",
   "message":"The identity type of the user is not supported.","code":13003}
}
```

Is there any other way to get more granular error information to see what might be the problem?

Comment: I've not seen a lot of stack overflow posts around this topic and none of them mentioned how to obtain better error information. The ms docs just say that I need to be a work account, which I am.

Comment: Help for 130xx errors is at [Troubleshoot SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins). One cause of 13003 is that you were logged into Office at an earlier time under an unsupported ID type. That credential wasn't entirely cleared when you logged in under a work account. Log out of Office and close all Office apps. Then reopen the Office app you are developing for and login again. Also, just a reminder: "work account" means M365 account, not a domain account in your company's LAN.

Comment: Yes, I had seen that. I've only logged in with that Office account. Yes, its a AAD account for our company's O365 subscription. I've tried clearing all account info from storage as needed but no luck.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Try closing all Office apps, [clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache), clear the browser cache, and reboot. If that doesn't fix it, try logging out of Office, closing all Office apps, and then have another user sit at your machine and log into Office. See if that user gets the same error.